# Error after installing proprietary driver for graphic card

Tags: drivers

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 + gnome 3. Before I installed proprietary
driver for my discrete card, Everything had worked fine (System
indicator, Activities corner, dash,...). After installing the driver,
the interface corrupted. Everything's gone except for a bar which
contain: File, Edit, View, Help,.... and the desktop, I cannot use Alt+F2
nor windows button

Even when I uninstalled the driver, nothing's changed :'(
I doubt that the proprietary driver hasn't been entirely removed or
the system cannot switch to the old Integrated card.
How can I get things back?

Comment: Sounds to me like your window decorator is hosed.  compiz --replace ccp & is where I would start looking

Comment: @aking1012 Nope, Window decorator is fine. What I means is the taskbar and the system indicator bar has gone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with proprietary driver from AMD. Leave the proprietary driver installed and try to delete the .compiz-1 folder in your home directory and login again.
If you do that with Nautilus, please check that you can see hidden files and folders in folder view.

Comment: i have no idea if it's right, but it sounds totally reasonable

Answer (score 0):

You need to completely uninstall the driver and re-install it again

There is a very detailed answer on this [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11326398&postcount=5) that should help you solve the problem.